# htaccess 301 Redirect is not working with RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in the site's htaccess file to apply a redirect on old images but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^image\.axd$ /wp-content/uploads/upload%1? [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

When i type these urls, it does not work. I would like also replace %2F with /

- `http://www.example.com/image.axd?picture=2012/1/sata-ide_lg.jpg`
- `http://www.example.com/image.axd?picture=%2F2013%2F04%2Fmicro_sim-001-en.jpg`

I would like these new urls to appear (301).

- `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/upload/2012/1/sata-ide_lg.jpg`
- `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/upload/2013/04/micro_sim-001-en.jpg`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? Does it do anything? Incorrect redirect? Is that the complete rule? (The `%1` makes no sense unless you have additional _conditions_.) What other directives do you have?

Comment: Hi, for the first url i solved by adding a slash before%1 RewriteRule ^image\.axd$ /wp-content/uploads/upload/%1? [L,NC,NE,R=301]. For the second URL i get the redirect but i have to replace% 2F with the slash and i don't know how to do it. Result is this: http://www.example.comt/wp-content/uploads/upload%2F2013%2F04%2Fmicro_sim-001-en.jpg

Comment: Although, like I said above, the `%1` makes no sense by itself - the rule you've posted is incomplete. Can you also have URLs that include a slash prefix on the `picture` URL parameter value? It's just that the second URL includes a `%2F` prefix (an encoded slash).

Comment: Yes, you can have URL with prefix% 2F and URL without prefix but with slash. Those that have the prefix must be replaced with slash.